# web page layout with header, menu, content and footer

Tags: flexbox, sticky

I've almost got this working the way I want but the content area (a flexbox) is not filling up all available space.

The Header should scroll off the page when their is more content than can be viewed.

The menu should stay sticky at the top of the page.

The content should fill the available space (which it is not currently doing).

The footer should stay sticky at the bottom of the page.

Thanks for any help.

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <title>Title</title>

    <style>

      html, body {
        height: 100%;
    background-color: green;
    margin: 0;
      }

      .content {
        display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: yellow;
        flex-grow: 1;
    overflow-y: auto;
      }

      .header {
        height: 100px;
    background-color: orange;
      }

      .menu {
    height: 30px;
    background-color: pink;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
      }

      .footer {
        flex: 0 0 50px;
    position: fixed;
    width: 50%;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: aqua;
      }

    </style>

  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="header">
      Header
    </div>

    <div class="menu">
        menu
    </div>

    <div class="content">
        <p>First</p>
        <p>content (should fill the remaining space)</p>
        <p>content (should fill the remaining space)</p>
        <p>content (should fill the remaining space)</p>
        <p>content (should fill the remaining space)</p>
        <p>content (should fill the remaining space)</p>
        <p>content (should fill the remaining space)</p>
        <p>content (should fill the remaining space)</p>
        <p>content (should fill the remaining space)</p>
        <p>content (should fill the remaining space)</p>
        <p>Last</p>
    </div>

    <div class="footer">
      <p>footer</p>
    </div>

  </body>

</html>
```